# Migrations in CakePHP 4 not working correctly?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-4.x

I'm running a fresh install of CakePHP 4 and I'm trying to create an initial migration for the database. The migration itself is build correctly but the command fails to mark the migrations as done:

```
~/code$ bin/cake bake migration_snapshot Initial

Creating file /home/vagrant/code/config/Migrations/20200125204245_Initial.php
Wrote `/home/vagrant/code/config/Migrations/20200125204245_Initial.php`
Marking the migration 20200125204245_Initial as migrated...
Exception: Shell class for "Migrations" could not be found. If you are trying to use a plugin shell, that was loaded via $this->addPlugin(), you may need to update bin/cake.php to match https://github.com/cakephp/app/tree/master/bin/cake.php
In [/home/vagrant/code/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Console/ShellDispatcher.php, line 332]
```

Since the migration is created successfully I'm pretty sure the plugin is installed correctly but somehow Bake can't access it?

The installed versions are:

- CakePHP 4.0.2
- CakePHP/Bake 2.0.4
- CakePHP/Migrations 3.0.0-beta2

Comment: I have the same exception, but `..._Initial.php` file is created correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently it's a bug and an issue has been created:

https://github.com/cakephp/bake/issues/638